# How to map through array merge getting the same for each result [lodash]

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I’m trying to merge lessons with user progress data. I believe I have a pointer issue.

I've had success with the inner merge of the two arrays. The issue comes with looping through users and not getting the right lesson data with the progress data attached.

## lessons data

```
   let lessons = [
     {“id”: “0106c568-70c0-4e56-8139-8e7f7d124f95",},
     {“id”: “033e18a2-d470-4fd7-8bdc-53e610f3f784",},
     {“id”: “d60f751c-d7d2-4dc6-9eda-a03bc5ebddc6",},
   ];
```

## all users’ progresses

```
const usersProgresses = [
     [
       {
         “id”: “cjrtmj9d601b908559oxe8hwk”,
         “lesson”: “0106c568-70c0-4e56-8139-8e7f7d124f95",
         “score”: null,
       },
       {
         “id”: “cjrtmk2hv01bx0855yof2ehj4”,
         “lesson”: “033e18a2-d470-4fd7-8bdc-53e610f3f784”,
         “score”: 100,
       },
       {
         “id”: “cjrtmlohd01cp0855jnzladye”,
         “lesson”: “3724d7df-311c-46d9-934f-a9c44d9335ae”,
         “score”: 20,
       }
     ],
     ...
   ];
```

## loop through users and merge progresses in lessons

```
   // for each user
   const result = usersProgresses.map(user => {
     // merge progress and lesson data by lesson.id
     const mergedProgress = [...lessons].map(lesson => {
       return _.merge(lesson,_ .find(userProgress, { lesson: lesson.id }));
     });
     return mergedProgress;
   });
```

Expected data out of `result`:

```
   [
     [
       {
         “id”: “0106c568-70c0-4e56-8139-8e7f7d124f95”,
         “lesson”: “0106c568-70c0-4e56-8139-8e7f7d124f95”,
         “score”: null,
       },
       {
         “id”: “033e18a2-d470-4fd7-8bdc-53e610f3f784",
         “lesson”: “033e18a2-d470-4fd7-8bdc-53e610f3f784",
         “score”: 100,
       },
       {
         “id”: “d60f751c-d7d2-4dc6-9eda-a03bc5ebddc6”,
       }
     ]
   ]
```

but getting:

```
   [
     [
       {
         “id”: “0106c568-70c0-4e56-8139-8e7f7d124f95”,
       },
       {
         “id”: “033e18a2-d470-4fd7-8bdc-53e610f3f784”,
       },
       {
         “id”: “d60f751c-d7d2-4dc6-9eda-a03bc5ebddc6”,
       }
     ]
   ]
```

Comment: Here is an example of the above: https://codepen.io/brantley/pen/jdYrZa?editors=0011

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this using a nested [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in vanilla js:

```js
const lessons = [{"id":"0106c568-70c0-4e56-8139-8e7f7d124f95",},{"id":"033e18a2-d470-4fd7-8bdc-53e610f3f784",},{"id":"d60f751c-d7d2-4dc6-9eda-a03bc5ebddc6",}]

const usersProgress = [[{"id":"cjrtmj9d601b908559oxe8hwk","lesson":"0106c568-70c0-4e56-8139-8e7f7d124f95","score":null,},{"id":"cjrtmk2hv01bx0855yof2ehj4","lesson":"033e18a2-d470-4fd7-8bdc-53e610f3f784","score":100,},{"id":"cjrtmlohd01cp0855jnzladye","lesson":"3724d7df-311c-46d9-934f-a9c44d9335ae","score":20,}]]

const output = usersProgress.map(user => lessons.map(lesson =>
    ({...user.find(p => p.lesson == lesson.id), ...lesson }))
 );
  
console.log(output)
```

Comment: Didn't noticed. after change my solution will turn out to be same as yours so deleted. +1

Answer (score 0):

```js
        const usersProgresses = [
            [
            {
                "id": "cjrtmj9d601b908559oxe8hwk",
                "lesson": "0106c568-70c0-4e56-8139-8e7f7d124f95",
                "score": null,
            },
            {
                "id": "cjrtmk2hv01bx0855yof2ehj4",
                "lesson": "033e18a2-d470-4fd7-8bdc-53e610f3f784",
                "score": 100,
            },
            {
                "id": "cjrtmlohd01cp0855jnzladye",
                "lesson": "3724d7df-311c-46d9-934f-a9c44d9335ae",
                "score": 20,
            }
            ],
        ];

        let lessons = [
            {"id": "0106c568-70c0-4e56-8139-8e7f7d124f95",},
            {"id": "033e18a2-d470-4fd7-8bdc-53e610f3f784",},
            {"id": "d60f751c-d7d2-4dc6-9eda-a03bc5ebddc6",},
        ];


        const mergedProgress = usersProgresses.map((Progresses) => {
            return [...lessons].map(lesson => {
                return Object.assign(lesson, Progresses.find((i) => i.lesson === lesson.id));
            });
        })

        console.log(mergedProgress)
```

Comment: Please use `console.log(JSON.stringify(mergedProgress))` and show your result as text rather than an image. This makes the answer more accessible for people.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`_.keyBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#keyBy) to create a dictionary of user lessons by lesson id. When creating the result object, get the lesson by the id using brackets notation, and spread it (`undefined` values would be ignored).

```js
const lessons = [{"id":"0106c568-70c0-4e56-8139-8e7f7d124f95",},{"id":"033e18a2-d470-4fd7-8bdc-53e610f3f784",},{"id":"d60f751c-d7d2-4dc6-9eda-a03bc5ebddc6",}]

const usersProgress = [[{"id":"cjrtmj9d601b908559oxe8hwk","lesson":"0106c568-70c0-4e56-8139-8e7f7d124f95","score":null,},{"id":"cjrtmk2hv01bx0855yof2ehj4","lesson":"033e18a2-d470-4fd7-8bdc-53e610f3f784","score":100,},{"id":"cjrtmlohd01cp0855jnzladye","lesson":"3724d7df-311c-46d9-934f-a9c44d9335ae","score":20,}]]

const result = usersProgress.map(user => {
  const lessonsById = _.keyBy(user, 'lesson') // create a dictionary of lesson by id

  return lessons.map(({ id }) => ({
    ...lessonsById[id], // get the lesson or undefined if not found, and spread
    id
  }))
});
   
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```